# Convert multipoint to point in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, point, multipoint

I have a table in SQL Server where points are stored as a mix of point and multipoint although all are just points. Unfortunately, the multipoints are causing problems elsewhere, so I need to convert them to points.

Is there a simple procedure for this? I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Please read this: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I fail to see how adding script or sample data will clarify my question. It is straight forward whether there is a procedure to convert multipoint((x,y)) to point(x,y) in SQL Server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

update MyTable
  set MyGeometry = MyGeometry.STGeometryN(1).STAsText()
  where MyGeometry.STAsText() like 'Multi%';

Comment: This is giving an error as follows >>>

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 8
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "enforce_srid_geometry_MyTable".